# angularjs unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

There are a lot of unknown provider questions on stack overflow, and I've looked at a couple of them so far, but none of them solve my problem. If I find one that does, I'll remove this question.

This is what my code looks like, ExpenseTracker is an `angular.module`:

```
ExpenseTracker.run(["$provide", "$q",function($provide, $q){
    console.log("define gapi service")
    window.gapiinit = function($q, $provide){
        var gapiPromise = $q.defer().promise;
        var ROOT = 'https://localhost:1800/_ah/api';
        gapi.client.load('expensetTackerapi', 'v1', function() {
                gapiPromise.resolve(gapi);
},      ROOT);
        $provide.factory("gapi",function(){
            return gapiPromise
        })
    }
}]
```

the error looks like this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $provideProvider <- $provide
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24provideProvider%20%3C-%20%24provide
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$provide` is a provider, you can only inject `$provide` in `app.config` method, not in `.run` method.

Comment: If I'm trying to use the $provide in a test fixture. What's the proper way of injecting $provide in this case?

Comment: @Blake $provide methods are directly available on app variable (returned by `angular.module()`). I don't know if this is what you wanted.